# How to stop removing added class on click again on the element?

Tags: jquery, magento2.1

I have size swatches on a page. When I click on swatch "selected" class add to the clicked swatches. 
If I clicked again then the added class is removing.

I want to stop removing the class on again click on that element.

HTML:

```
<div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
<div class="swatch-option text selected" option-type="0" option-id="143" option-label="L" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="L">L</div>
<div class="swatch-option text" option-type="0" option-id="142" option-label="XL" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="XL">XL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the jquery code that is used to add the class?

Comment: I don't know, from where is it coming?

Comment: do you mean the code executed on click is not yours?

Comment: yes, this is not coded by me. I want to stop removing the class on click again on the same element.

Comment: @OwaisAslam: I suspect that the behavior is coming from a plugin included by OP. Anyways, You can simply disable `click` event to avoid it. Just include `$(".swatch-attribute-options .swatch-option").on("click", function() {$(this).off("click")})` towards the end of your javascript

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Yeah, I got it that's why removed my comment! :)

Comment: Find the code that's adding it and fix that.

Comment: please check my edits

Comment: could you please point me to the place in your html where this problem is occurring because I can´t find it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the behavior is coming from a library that you are using. To override the behavior, simply disable `click` event callback after the first click. But beware, this will also disable any other actions that were defined in your `click` callback.

**Original Answer:** *(This solution will fail for OP because it is evident from the comments that the `click` event has more handles after selection. See the update to the answer at bottom of my post)*
Add this towards the end of your javascript on the page:

```
$(".swatch-attribute-options .swatch-option").on("click", function() {
  $(this).off("click");
});
```

[Demo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5rfthprk/5/)

If you suspect there are more events in callback, simply add the class `selected` again. This will momentarily remove the selection but will add it back almost instantly unless there are any time consuming activity in the plugin code that handles `click` event.

```
$(".swatch-attribute-options .swatch-option").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected"));
});
```

**Update based on comment(s):**
This should keep the only last selection and wont unselect if clicked again. Also, it will not block any subsequent handles in your `click` event

```
$(".swatch-attribute-options .swatch-option").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".swatch-option").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rfthprk/11/)

Comment: I want to select only one at a time

Comment: Do you mean select only one swatch and unselect any previously selected ones?

Comment: Yes, and same element not clicked again.

Comment: Here two swatches, after loading nothing selected. When we select swatch then "selected class" added, but when we click again then this element unselect. If a user select swatch then it must be selected at least one of them

Comment: Check updated answer. To remove all selections on load, just remove `selected` class from frost swatch in your HTML. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rfthprk/11/)

Answer (score 0):

If the code removing the `selected` class comes from an external handler, try putting this code where you are sure will run before that handler (preferably as high as possible among your *includes*).

**Notice this will also cancel any other action inside the external handler**

This is an example of how you could go about for preventing undesired code from running. I included two handlers, the second shouldn't run as a demonstration of what should happen to your unwanted code.

Let me know if it works

```js
$('.swatch-option').click(function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings('.swatch-option').removeClass('selected');
  alert('notice how "unwanted code" does not run');
});

$('.swatch-option').click(function(e){
  alert('unwanted code');
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
<div class="swatch-option text selected" option-type="0" option-id="143" option-label="L" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="L">L</div>
<div class="swatch-option text" option-type="0" option-id="142" option-label="XL" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="XL">XL</div>
<div class="swatch-option text selected" option-type="0" option-id="143" option-label="L" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="L">L</div>
<div class="swatch-option text" option-type="0" option-id="142" option-label="XL" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="XL">XL</div>
<div class="swatch-option text" option-type="0" option-id="143" option-label="L" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="L">L</div>
<div class="swatch-option text" option-type="0" option-id="142" option-label="XL" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="XL">XL</div>
<div class="swatch-option text selected" option-type="0" option-id="143" option-label="L" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="L">L</div>
<div class="swatch-option text" option-type="0" option-id="142" option-label="XL" option-tooltip-thumb="" option-tooltip-value="XL">XL</div>

</div>
```

Comment: After using this code, I am unable to add product into the cart.

Comment: so indeed the unwanted code runs after yours and it does more than just toggling `selected` class, right? so you need a solution that prevents only the toggling of the class but leaves all other behaviour as is, correct?

Comment: That's because of `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` which is preventing the rest of the handlers from being executed in the `click` event.

Comment: can we use alternate of  e.stopImmediatePropagation()